# Multiple sub-figures arranged on one page

Tags: latex, figure, subfigure

I would like to arrange 4 sets of 3 subfigures onto one page as shown in the attached picture. I want each of the 4 sets of subfigures to have their own figure number and caption.
Is it possible to split the page into quarters in which I could place the subfigure?
[image].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can place your subfigure collections inside a `minipage`. Each one has a number of `\subcaption`s and its own `\caption`. Spacing can be changed as needed.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx,subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \begin{minipage}{.48\linewidth}
    \centering
    \subcaptionbox{First top left}
      {\includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=50pt]{example-image-a}}

    \subcaptionbox{Second top left}
      {\includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=50pt]{example-image-b}}

    \subcaptionbox{Third top left}
      {\includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=50pt]{example-image-c}}

    \caption{Top left}
  \end{minipage}\quad
  \begin{minipage}{.48\linewidth}
    \centering
    \subcaptionbox{First top right}
      {\includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=50pt]{example-image-a}}

    \subcaptionbox{Second top right}
      {\includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=50pt]{example-image-b}}

    \subcaptionbox{Third top right}
      {\includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=50pt]{example-image-c}}

    \caption{Top right}
  \end{minipage}

  \bigskip

  \begin{minipage}{.48\linewidth}
    \centering
    \subcaptionbox{First bottom left}
      {\includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=50pt]{example-image-a}}

    \subcaptionbox{Second bottom left}
      {\includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=50pt]{example-image-b}}

    \subcaptionbox{Third bottom left}
      {\includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=50pt]{example-image-c}}

    \caption{Bottom left}
  \end{minipage}\quad
  \begin{minipage}{.48\linewidth}
    \centering
    \subcaptionbox{First bottom right}
      {\includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=50pt]{example-image-a}}

    \subcaptionbox{Second bottom right}
      {\includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=50pt]{example-image-b}}

    \subcaptionbox{Third bottom right}
      {\includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=50pt]{example-image-c}}

    \caption{Bottom right}
  \end{minipage}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```